# Why Does My GIMP Python Plug-In Not Work on My Ubuntu Linux Box?

Tags: python, linux, gimp

I am trying to write my own Python plug-in for the GNU Image Manipulation Plug-In. I was following this tutorial at this URL: http://gimpbook.com/scripting/slides/index.html. I changed some of the variable names and named the script something different but basically it is the same script.

The script works when calling it from the interactive GIMP Python shell. I access by doing this with the mouse: "**Filters -> Python-Fu -> Console**". Here the `hello_world()` function works.

However, when I put the plug-in in the `.gimp2.8/plugins/` folder or the `/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins` I am not able to see the plug-in in the `Plug-In Browser` after going to `Help -> Plug-In Browser`. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Regards,

My source-code for the Python GIMP plug-in is below...

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 


from gimpfu import * 

def hello_world(initstr, font, size, color):
    img = gimp.Image(1, 1, RGB) 
    gimp.set_foreground(color)
    layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(img, None, 0, 0, initstr, 10, True, size, PIXELS, font) 
    img.resize(layer.width, layer.height, 0, 0)
    gimp.Display(img) 

register( 
  "pythonic_easier_gimp",
  "Hello Gimp Image", "Hello gimp image",
  "My Name", "My Name", "2015", 
  "Easier gimp...",
  "",
  [ 
     (PF_STRING, "string", "String", 'Hello, Gimp!'),
     (PF_FONT, "font", "Font face", "Sans")
     (PF_SPINNER, "size", "Font size", 50, (1, 3000, 1)),
     (PF_COLOR, "color", "Text color", (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))

  ], 
  [], 
  easier_gimp, menu="<Image>/File/Create")


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution! I read a few tutorials online and switched to a different development environment, Eclipse using the PyDev plug-in. PyDev was able to point out syntax errors in the overly complex `register()` function.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 

from gimpfu import *

def wonka():
    img = gimp.Image(1, 1, RGB)
    gimp.set_foreground('purple')
    layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(img, None, 0, 0, 'Willy Wonka!', 10, True, 90, PIXELS, 'comic sans')
    img.resize(layer.width, layer.height, 0, 0)
    gimp.Display(img)



register(
         "wonka",
         "Prints a message from Willy Wonka",
         "Prints a message from Willy Wonka",
         "User3870315",
         "User3870315",
         "2015",

         "<Toolbox>/Tools/Wonka",
         "",
         [],
         [],
         wonka)


main()
```

This shows up in the `Filters -> Python-Fu -> Console -> Browse`. It also shows up in the toolbar under `Tools`.

These links helped:

- http://gimpforums.com/thread-plugin-registration-problems
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-autogimp/index.html

Answer (score 3):

If the script does not show on the menus it means the call to "register" and "main" above is not being run. One possibility is that you have not marked your Python file with the exectutable permission. (Check the file properties, or run `chmod 777 myfile.py` on it)

Another possibility is a Python syntax error - that could be difficult to spot giving the listing - to check for syntax errors, try just running the script as a normal Python program from the shell: `$ python myfile.py` - that should yield an `ImportError`. If you see a `SyntaxError`, fix that instead.

And finally, with the plug-in in place, start it from the terminal, instead of the menus - if GIMP found your plug-in but stumbled on an error on it, it should display a `Wire read error` on the terminal output: it also could indicate a Python syntax error, or incorrect call to `register` (too few or too many parameters). Since by this time you have ruled out syntax errors, double check your parameter count to `register`)

It should show up in the menus when you have fixed stuff thus far.

Comment: Thank-you @jsbueno for the helpful reply. :D I was able to figure it out on my own somehow, which entails reading lots of posts on the Internet and coding and testing it. Check out my solution below. This actually works but it is completely pointless. :D :/ :D

Comment: Not pointless: if you tried to run it wth Python from the console, as I point out, the error messages you'd see would point to the Syntax Error on the offending call.

Comment: Or tahter,y ou'd have a "tuple object is not callable" error, but it would point the correct line where to look for the error.

Comment: When you say, "...run it with Python from the console". Do you mean like `gimp script.py` or just `python script.py`?

Comment: Also, I meant the plug-in I coded was pointless as it only prints "willy wonka".

Answer (score 0):

2 problems with the code stood out to me the function/call mismatched and a missing delimiting comma

```py
(PF_FONT, "font", "Font face", "Sans") #<--missing comma
```

```py
def hello_world(initstr, font, size, color): #<--Defined function hello_world()
easier_gimp, menu="<Image>/File/Create") #<--plugin calls easier_gimp()
```

So adding the comma and renaming `hello_world` to `easier_gimp` allow the plugin to work.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python


from gimpfu import *

def easier_gimp(initstr, font, size, color):
    img = gimp.Image(1, 1, RGB)
    gimp.set_foreground(color)
    layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(img, None, 0, 0, initstr, 10, True, size, PIXELS, font)
    img.resize(layer.width, layer.height, 0, 0)
    gimp.Display(img)

register(
  "pythonic_easier_gimp",
  "Hello Gimp Image", "Hello gimp image",
  "My Name", "My Name", "2015",
  "Easier gimp...",
  "",
  [
     (PF_STRING, "string", "String", 'Hello, Gimp!'),
     (PF_FONT, "font", "Font face", "Sans"),
     (PF_SPINNER, "size", "Font size", 50, (1, 3000, 1)),
     (PF_COLOR, "color", "Text color", (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))

  ],
  [],
  easier_gimp, menu="<Image>/File/Create")


main()
```

Recently have been created Python based Hello World GIMP plugin examples in [this github project](https://github.com/CrandellWS/gimp-plugin-helloworld)